# Issue with stored procedure in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure that executes correctly when I run my program:

```
$insertIntoEmployeesProcedure = "
CREATE PROCEDURE EmployeeInsert(name VARCHAR(50),password VARCHAR(50), email VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO employees(name,password,email) values(name,password,email);
END";

$returnInsertIntoEmpProc = $conn->query($insertIntoEmployeesProcedure);

if(! $returnInsertIntoEmpProc )
{
    die('Could not create insert procedure: ' . $conn->error);
}

else
{
    echo "Insert Procedure created successfully<br/>";
}
```

I then call this procedure in another class when needed:

```
$insertEmp = mysqli_query($conn, "Call EmployeeInsert('$username','$password', '$email')"); 

            $executeInsertEmp = $conn->query($insertEmp);

            if(!$executeInsertEmp )
            {
                die('Employees not added: ' . $conn->error);
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Employees added<br/>";
            }
```

The problem is, when I execute this code, I get the following error

```
Employees not added: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1
```

The main issue I have with this is that even though it returns this error, the record is still added into the database and everything seems to be working fine. I guess I'm more curious as to why I'm getting this error as clearly I'm overlooking something.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I see what I've done, I seem to have added an additional query which was unnecessary, the line:

```
$executeInsertEmp = $conn->query($insertEmp);
```

can be ommited, the check in the if statement is then done on the variable which holds the stored procedure. The following code works:

```
$insertEmp = mysqli_query($conn, "Call EmployeeInsert('$username','$password', '$email')"); 

if(!$insertEmp )
{
     die('Employees not added: ' . $conn->error);
}
else
{
     echo "Employees added<br/>";
}
```